# Warning: ToastAndroid is not supported on this platform. error with react native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am getting this error on react native IOS,

```
- node_modules/expo/build/logs/LogSerialization.js:166:14 in _captureConsoleStackTrace
- node_modules/expo/build/logs/LogSerialization.js:41:24 in serializeLogDataAsync
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals
```

import { ToastAndroid } from 'react-native'
ToastAndroid.show('Somthing!', ToastAndroid.SHORT);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to use AndroidToast on IOS platform.

edit ur code so it only execute on Android Platform using Platform.OS

```
if (Platform.OS == 'android'){
    //ur android code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

keep android toast for android and use react-native-root-toast for ios :

```
npm install react-native-root-toast
```

import react-native-root-toast and wrap  in your main file App.js

```
import { RootSiblingParent } from 'react-native-root-siblings';
...

<RootSiblingParent>
<App />
</RootSiblingParent>
```

then call toast like that :

```
let m = "this is a toast";"ios"===Platform.OS?Toast.show(m,Toast.SHORT):ToastAndroid.show(m,ToastAndroid.SHORT);
```